# React Native Android Geolocation Not Returning - Dead Thread

Tags: android, react-native

Having a problem with fetching user's location on Android in React Native
I have setup the correct permissions and the location is being fetched but it is not making its way back to my component. Seeing the following in the logs

```
 W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1) {6456d95} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1) {6456d95} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
                                                               at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:543)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:507)
                                                               at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.onLocationChanged(LocationManager.java:248)
                                                               at android.location.ILocationListener$Stub.onTransact(ILocationListener.java:58)
                                                               at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:461)
```

Using react-native 0.25.01, targetSdk 23

Any ideas on why this might be happening? Would love some input :)
My implementation is just a copy paste from the docs (http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#content)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will be much help for you, but I have created a sample that works on Android (Genymotion Emulator).

It is running on react-native 0.26.3, you can see it on GitHub https://github.com/AidenMontgomery/react-native-sample

I have never seen the actual error that you are getting, but I know that having a working example often helps me get past issues with my code.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity sake use the following npm package, this was last tested in ReactNative 0.60.4.

```
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
```

Be sure to request permission for location services, this should be :

```
    //Request location permission
    async componentWillMount(){
        try {
            await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        } catch (err) {
            console.warn(err);
        }
    }
```

Define an async function to be used to pull your current location.

```
 _mapLocation = async () => {
        await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
                var x: LatLng = {
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                };

                //Here I am collecting gps coordinates in a collection.
                var tempMarkers = this.state.markers;
                tempMarkers.push({latlng: x, title: '', description: ''});
                this.setState({markers: tempMarkers});
            },
            error => {
                console.warn(error.message);
            },
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 10000 }
        )
    }
```

Finally here is an example of how to execute the newly created async function:

```
<Button title='Map Location' type='solid' onPress={() => this._mapLocation()} />
```